# Azure Data Factory: Read file from blob once and put it to two databases

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need to read file with JSON from blob once, then make some transformation put one part into database A and other into database B.

Let's say I have a file with the following content

```
{
  "SerialNumber": "FAKE1",
  "Connected": true,
  "Timestamp":1616148596068,
  "Sensors": [
    {
      "Number": "631",
      "Value": 9
    },
    {
      "Number": "600",
       "Value": 44
    }
  ]
}
```

As a database I use Cosmos DB.

To the database A should be inserted:

```
{
   "SerialNumber": "FAKE1",
   "Connected": true,
   "Timestamp":1616148596068
}
```

To the database B should be inserted 2 rows:

```
{
   "SerialNumber": "FAKE1",
   "Timestamp":1616148596068,
   "Number": "631",
   "Value": 9
}
{
   "SerialNumber": "FAKE1",
   "Timestamp":1616148596068,
   "Number": "600",
   "Value": 44
}
```

How it is possible to configure in Azure Data Factory Data Flow?
I've tried to use **Copy data** activity. In this case I need 2 almost the same activities that will read the same file twice.

Then I've tries to use ***Data flow**. But don't know how to foreach array and insert each row as a separate value into DB. What function can I use. Could anyone please help?

[image]

Please let me know if I need to add more information. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataflow is declarative meaning you don't write procedural logic like pipeline. Iterating via rows happens implicitly. I assume you are reading a JSON file and you want to split writing the header into one DB and details into another.

Dataflow will read the data once and parallelize writes to both the DBs.

You will extract header info into DB1 and you will use a flatten tx to extract the details to write to DB2.

DSL script snippet would look like

```
HeartBeats foldDown(unroll(Sensors), 
                   mapColumn(
                          SerialNumber, 
                          Timestamp, 
                          Sensors.Number,
                          Sensors.Value) 
                ) ~> HeartBeatsFlattened
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with two Copy activities like you say.

For database A just select the required fields in Mapping tab.

For database B you need to specify the array element as 'collection reference' - an example just like yours can be found in the docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#hierarchical-source-to-tabular-sink

Comment: Yes, you are right. It works. But in this case, the file will be copy from the blob 2 times. So, in a result I will get more traffic. Are there any ways how to avoid many reads opeartions?

Comment: True - so the choice depends I suppose on why you want to avoid the two reads.  Using dataflow means waiting for and paying for spinning up a Spark cluster.